# How to solve the error 'sh: 1: expo: not found'

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I'm very new to React Native and I'm trying to install the React Native environment of my Ubuntu 20.04 to get started. I am following a Udemy course and the instructor provided a sample project to run to get started. Since the instructor has only taught us to install it on Windows and Mac, I've tried to install it on my own.

#### What I have already done :

- I have installed npm and nodejs.

#### What I'm unable to do :

- I am unable to install expo-cli on my ubuntu. I have tried a bunch of methods and commands available on the internet, but no results.

When I run this command:

`npm install --global expo-cli`

I get the following error:

```
npm WARN @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.3.3 requires a peer of react-refresh@^0.8.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ expo-cli@4.0.16
```

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install react-refresh@^0.8.2
```

or

```
npm install --save react-refresh@^0.8.2
```

and try again

Comment: try to install it global too... npm install --gloabl react-refresh@^0.8.2